# how to access variables defined in other method

Tags: java, swing, methods

The requirement is that I need to access variables which are defined in the method **showTableData()**  from class **JTableModel extends AbstractTableModel**.I need to use the values section_name ,report_name,contact_name,link_name which are defined in showTableData() in the JTableModel. Now how to do that ?

```
public class r_search_2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  //code
    r_search_2() 
    {

      //code

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == b1)
        {
            showTableData();
        }
     }

    public void showTableData()
    {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

        table.setModel(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        from = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();
        if(from.equals(""))
        {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a search term", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {

        TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
        table.getColumn("METRICS").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
        //System.out.println(table.getColumn("METRICS"));
        //table.getColumn("Button2").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
        table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(table));

        String section_name = "";
        String report_name = "";
        String contact_name = "";
        String link = "";


        try
        {

        pst = con.prepareStatement("select distinct Section.Section_Name,Report.Report_Name,Report.Link,Contact.Contact_Name "
                                        + "FROM (( Section INNER JOIN Report ON Report.Section_ID=Section.Section_ID ) INNER JOIN Contact ON Contact.Contact_ID=Report.Contact_ID )  LEFT JOIN Metrics ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID  "
                                                                + " WHERE Section.Section_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Report.Report_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Metrics.Metric_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Contact.Contact_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' ");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                section_name = rs.getString("Section_Name");
                report_name = rs.getString("Report_Name");
                contact_name = rs.getString("Contact_Name");
                link = rs.getString("Link");
                data_values(section_name,report_name,contact_name,link);



                model.addRow(new Object[]{section_name, report_name, contact_name, link});

                i++;

            }


            if (i < 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        }
        mainPanel.add(scroll);

        mainPanel.revalidate();
        mainPanel.repaint();

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          //code
    }
}
```

Comment: by using mutators: setters and getters

Comment: Why dont you define those variable as class level variable and provide getters only for accessing those variable externally (in other class)?

Comment: @Stultuske:Yes..I thought in this direction only. But the problem is that the return type for showTableData() is void as it is accessed from method actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae). Now if the method has to return string (as i need to return variables as section_name etc)I will have to change the return type for showTableData as well. So, now can you help me guiding as to how to do that ? Thanks !

Comment: showTableData is a method, not the entire class.
it's also not a mutator. in your actionperformed, you can (for instance) store the data you need later on in an instance variable, and use a mutator (getter) to get that information.

Comment: I think I'll again face the problem of return type for methods.can you please show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that your key variables are all local to the showTableData method, and thus are only visible within that method. If you want to use mutator and accessor methods, then make your TableModel a field, and give the class methods to extract data from the model, or add or change data in the model (only through the model's methods though).

So:

```
public class SomeClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public Object getRowData(int row) {
       if (model != null) {
          // return row of data from model here 
       } else {
          // throw some exception
       }
    }


    SomeClass() 
    {

      //code
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == b1)
        {
            showTableData();
        }
     }

    public void showTableData()
    {
        // DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(); // don't re-declare the model here

        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        table.setModel(model);
```

You also need to review some basic Java tutorials about accessors/mutators also known as getters/setters. We won't be able to help you much til you understand the rudiments of basic Java first.

Comment: @user3: it's called wherever it is needed, wherever another class needs access to the table data.